# Keychain data gets deleted when the app is not used for a long time

Tags: ios, flutter, keychain

I am having a strange issue in my app, I store all tokens in secure storage (it stores data in Keychain under the hood) in my Flutter app and it's working perfectly for most of the users but one of my users didn't use the app actively for weeks (or even a month) and app was either in background or terminated state. Today he opened the app and noticed that all requests to the server didn't work. We found out that when we try to get the token from secure storage it returns null. What might be the reason for this? Does the iOS delete the data from Keychain if it's not active for some time? Thank you for that answer in advance:)